# Mule Functional Tests - totally confused

Tags: esb, mule

We have a Mule application with 6 or seven flows with around 5 components per flow.
Here is the setup.
We send JMS requests to an ActiveMQ Queue. Mule listens to that. Based on content of the message we forward that to corresponding flows.

```
 <flow name="MyAPPAutomationFlow" doc:name="MyAPPAutomationFlow">
      <composite-source>
            <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="MyAPPOrderQ" connector-ref="Active_MQ_1" doc:name="AMQ1 Inbound Endpoint"/>
            <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="MyAPPOrderQ" connector-ref="Active_MQ_2" doc:name="AMQ2 Inbound Endpoint"/>
      </composite-source>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="payload.getProcessOrder().getOrderType().toString().equals(&quot;ANC&quot;)" evaluator="groovy">
                <processor-chain>
                    <flow-ref name="ProcessOneFLow" doc:name="Go to ProcessOneFLow"/>
                </processor-chain>
            </when>
            <when....
            ...........


         </choice>
    </flow>


 <flow name="ProcessOneFLow" doc:name="ProcessOneFLow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="ProcessOneFLow" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="New Process Order"/>
        <component doc:name="Create A">
            <spring-object bean="createA"/>
        </component>
        <component doc:name="Create B">
            <spring-object bean="createB"/>
        </component>
        <component doc:name="Create C">
            <spring-object bean="createC"/>
        </component>
        <component doc:name="Create D">
            <spring-object bean="createD"/>
        </component>    
</flow>


 <spring:beans>

    <spring:import resource="classpath:spring/service.xml"/>
    <spring:bean id="createA" name="createA" class="my.app.components.CreateAService"/>
    <spring:bean id="createB" name="createB" class="my.app.components.CreateBService"/>
    <spring:bean id="createC"  name="createC" class="my.app.components.CreateCService"/>
    <spring:bean id="createD" name="createD" class="my.app.components.CreateDService"/>
            ......
            ......
 </spring:beans>
```

Now I am not sure how I can write Functional tests with them.

I went through the Functional Testing documentation in Mule website but there they have very simple tests.

Is Functional Testing not supposed to make actual backend updates using DAO or Service layers or is it just an extension of Unit tests where you mock up service layer?

I was of the idea - it can take in a request and use the inmemory Mule server to pass the request-response from one component to another in a flow. 
Also kindly note there is no Outbound endpoint for any of our flows as they are mostly Fire and Forget type flows and status updates are managed by the DB updates the components do.

Also why do I need to create separate mule config xml files for tests? If I am not testing the flow xml that will actually be deployed on Live what's the point of this testing? I f I am creating separate xml configs just for tests that somewhat defeats the purpose to me...
Can some expert kindly elucidate a bit more and point to example tests similar to the ones we are using.

PS: the components inside Mule are dependent on external systems like webservices, databases etc. For Functional tests do we need to have those running or are we supposed to mock out those services/Db Access?

Comment: Before replying to this one, what did you think of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13609415/387927 ?

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the answer to that thread.

Comment: Hi David. if you could kindly answer the question in this thread.. looking forward to your explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional testing your Mule application is no different from testing any application that relies on external resources, like databases or JMS brokers, so you need to use the same techniques you would do with a standard application.

Usually this means stubbing the resources out with in-memory implementations, like HSQLDB for databases or a transient ActiveMQ in-memory broker for JMS. For a Mule application, this implies modularizing your configuration so "live" transports are defined in a separate file, which you replace with one that contains the in-memory variants at testing time.

To validate Mule had the correct interaction with the resource, you can either read the resource directly using its Java client (for example JDBC or JMS), which is good if you want to ensure that purely non-Mule clients have no issue reading what Mule has dispatched, or use the MuleClient to read from these resources or create flows that consume these resources and pass messages to the `<test:component>`.

> FYI These different techniques are explained and demonstrated in chapter 12 of [Mule in Action, second edition](http://manning.com/dossot2/).

Comment: Thanks David. Well in our applcation we are using spring jdbc to connect to DB and also using Spring Webservices to connect to external webservices and not relying on Mule for the same. How do you reckon we should handle that situation?    Also can you kindly answer why need to wrote separate mule-config xmls for tests? Should we not be able to test teh actual Production config xml as thats what we are testing. Creating separate files kind of defeats the purpose

Comment: Use whatever technique is recommended by Spring to test the beans that use Spring JDBC and webservice, this has nothing to do with Mule. If you intend to run your tests against the production infrastructure then use a single file but you'll need to flag these messages as test ones otherwise you'll mess production data. And no it doesn't defeat any purpose: there's value in testing in isolation, for example to prove that the flows, the transformers they contain, etc... behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks David. When I said running tests against production infratructure I meant the same flow file that is deployed in production. However while running the tests I will be stubbing out external services and databases and also point to test versions of the same instead of Live sources. I have noticed in Mule docs that they kind of copy the flow xml file into a new test file and write tests on them. e.g in future if I change the actual flow xml file I also need to copy the same changes in another test file. One would expect to run tests and Live on the same piece of code i.e. flow config file

Comment: Re-read my answer: you only extract the transport config in another config file and replace this one with stubs at test time. The config that contains all the flows remains the same for tests and prod.

Comment: yep. that' what I did now. Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/01/mule-esb-testing-part-13-unit-functional-testing/

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Functional+Testing
Please refer this links
As you can see, it's an ordinary JUnit test extending FunctionalMunitSuite class.
There are two thing we need to do in our test:

Prepare MuleEvent object as an input to our flow. We can do that by using provided testEvent(Object payload) method.
Execute runFlow(String flowName, MuleEvent event) method specifying flow name to test against and event we just created in the first step.

Comment: Please do not use links in your answer. When the link goes down, your answer becomes useless... Try to write a meaningfull answer with the information in the links.